# problem to insert data in mysql database with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

i want create table in mysql database but it dose not work

here is what i tried

```
                                                     # create a table

tables['email_ad4'] = ('CREATE TABLE `email_ad4`('
                   ' `username` VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,'
                   ' `password` VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL, '
                          'PRIMARY KEY (username))')

for table_name in tables:
    table_description = tables[table_name]
    try:
        print("Creating table {}: ".format(table_name), end='')
        cursor.execute(table_description)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR:
            print("already exists.")
        else:
            print(err.msg)
    else:
        print("OK")

                                                     # insert data to table

add_email = ('INSERT INTO email_ad'
             '(username , password)'
             'VALUES (%s , %s)')


data_email = ('a, password')                         # a, password are strings
cursor.execute(add_email, data_email)

cnx.commit()
```

output

```
connecting...
connected.
Creating table email_ad5: OK


raise errors.get_exception(packet)

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s , %s)' at line 1
```

it connect to mysql server and create table
i do not know why got this error,
any clue thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `data_email` be a `tuple`? It's a `string`, unfortunately. However, that still might not solve the problem.

Comment: I think the line `data_email = ('a, password')` should look like `data_email = ('a', 'password')`. That is because right now, you only have one element in the `data_email` tuple instead of two.

Comment: i try this  `data_email = ('a', 'password')`  but do not work ```raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement```

Comment: `data_email = ('a', 'password')` works for me (once the table name in the insert statement is corrected.  Are you sure you are sharing the correct code?

Comment: i am pretty sure that is right code  ```connecting...
connected.
Creating table email_ad8: OK
created
Enter your email : mraram77@gmail.com
Enter your password : 123456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/New folder (4)/untitled/milan/mysql2.py", line 76, in <module>
    cursor.execute(add_email, data_email)
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 560, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement```and take this error